# batch file for-loop fails to find text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to use the following code to grab the name of the drive users have named "New Volume" in order to automate some of our test cases at my company.

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumeName > c:\batch_script.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (c:\batch_script.txt) do echo %%A
PAUSE
```

Now I've gotten a few different runtime problems with this file; the first 2/3 times I run the file, I'm informed that the system can't find the file "c:\batch_script.txt", but after the 3rd try, I don't get the message that the system can't find the file anymore.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is the wmic command messing up my file privileges? (as I have to run the batch file as Administrator to get the wmic command to run)

Thanks again for all the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ran the script with admin permissions?
If the C:\ is the windows drive you need an admin permsissions to create a file there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that `wmic` may be invoking some executable that is actually creating the file, but `wmic` itself returns immediately. I can't see it happening on my system, but perhaps...

Hence, maybe delete the target file (I'd choose to make a file under `%temp%` to avoid security issues) then deliberately wait (or investigate whether some executable appears using `tasklist` and wait for *that* to terminate)

Regardless, `wmic` output is unicode, so you'd need

```
for /f ... %%A in ('type "yourfilename"') do ...
```

to ascify it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you see the results you are reporting. But the following will give you what you want.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "volumeName='System Reserved'" get caption'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```

The extra FOR /F loop is used to trim an extra, unwanted carriage return that is at the end of each line of WMIC output when it is processed directly by FOR /F. The WMIC output is unicode, and there is a FOR /F anomaly that mysteriously appends the extra carriage return when it converts the WMIC output to ANSI.